# carousel issue | Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

I am using Angular 6 and I have topAdvertisementList[] is returning 2 records to be shown in my carousel with a fixed image to be shown, but I see only one record is shown in the carousel!, I think something wrong in my HTML script.

could you please assist ?

```html
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li *ngFor="let add of topAdvertisementList;  let i=index"
            data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="i" class="active"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div *ngFor="let add of topAdvertisementList; let i=index" [ngClass]="{
                    'carousel-item active':i === 0,
                    'carousel-item':i > 0 }">
                <img src="assets/modules/dummy-assets/common/img/photos/1.jpeg" alt="{{i}}">
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: @jason, I couldn’t find any difference between my and ur script?!!

Comment: there is  a difference. You can check the post revision. Your code was not well formated.

Comment: I would tag your post with bootstrap and bootstrap-carousel to get more focused attention.  Also can you inspect the carousel and tell if two divs are actually being created?  Since you have the same image url hard-coded I wonder if bootstrap-carousel isn't eliminating the duplicate based on src...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Format is not the problem, correct script is

```html
                    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                            <li *ngFor="let add of topAdvertisementList; index as i" data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="i" class="active"></li>
                        </ol>
                        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                            <div *ngFor="let add of topAdvertisementList; index as i" [ngClass]="{
                                        'carousel-item active':i == 0,
                                        'carousel-item':i >= 0}">
                                <img *ngIf="add.adv_file" src="{{genericService.baseUrl}}/{{add.adv_file}}" alt="Advertisement">
                                <img *ngIf="!add.adv_file" src="assets/images/no-image.jpg" alt="Advertisement">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                        </a>
                        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
                            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
```

Comment: The only changes I made to the script were to remove all the blank padding to the left and to move a couple of the attributes to a new line so they can be more easily seen without scrolling.  That is easier to read and better to get more answers and for other people that might find your question when searching a similar problem.  At the very least you should remove the padding to the left by unindenting it in an editor.  Please delete this 'answer' too since it isn't really an answer.